# disable a key on an OS level

Tags: shortcut-keys, system, vim, customization

I have a volume control wheel on the bases of my laptop which I always spin by mistake. When spun, the letters `6` `~` start to pop up in rapid succession.

Annoying as this is, when in my `vim` environment, it starts to run along my sentence and change the case of all my characters. This is not the only problem, this is the most inconvenient one though.

I have tried adding the following to my `.vimrc` but this isn't working as predicted:

```
(N,v,I)noremap <ctrl+v+vol_wheel> <nop>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First find out the keycode, launch this command

   ```
   xev
   ```
2. Then scroll the wheel
3. To disable it run:

   ```
   xmodmap -e "keycode <number-from-command-above> = 0x0000"
   ```

Reference: [Multimediakeys with `.Xmodmap` HOWTO](http://cweiske.de/howto/xmodmap/allinone.html)