# Unbinding mouse buttons in Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: mouse, shortcut-keys

My mouse (a Logitech G700) has a broken button that continuously depresses. I'm looking for a way to tell the computer to ignore that button, it's currently bound to the dash key and it makes things annoying by dropping dashes keystrokes around randomly. Ideally I'd want not only Ubuntu but any applications to not do anything when that mouse button is pressed.

Thanks!

The xev information for that key is:

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4200001,
    root 0x4b4, subw 0x4200002, time 2303555, (42,53), root:(2027,105),
    state 0x10, keycode 82 (keysym 0xffad, KP_Subtract), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2d) "-"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2d) "-"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: Same as this one ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/280971/disable-a-key-on-an-os-level

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help.

## Step 1

- Go to this link
- [How to configure extra buttons in Logitech Mouse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152297/how-to-configure-extra-buttons-in-logitech-mouse)

## Step 2

- Follow guide.
- Profit.

Comment: That doesn't specify how to UNBIND buttons, but how to BIND different functions to them actually.

Answer (score 0):

My answer at this link was accepted for something quite similar just today!

Hope this helps.

[Enable/disable mousekeys via command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786509/enable-disable-mousekeys-via-command-line/786525?noredirect=1#comment1180504_786525)